# How to upload images to MaterialTable table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I want to add a column to upload images so they can be sent to a backend.
I'm using custom rendering and it shows images i have in my database it is just that i can't upload them from the table.

[image: the row actually shows the image]
The row actually shows the image

[image: This is what it looks like when i try to upload data to the table]

This is what it looks like when i try to upload data to the table

This is the code of my custom component

```
                            {
                            title: 'Imágen', field: 'image',
                            render: rowData =>
                                <img src={rowData.image} alt={rowData.description} style={{ width: 75 }} />
                            ,
                            editComponent: () => {
                                return (
                                    <>
                                        <input
                                            type='file'
                                            onChange={e => {
                                                setProductImage(e.target.files[0])
                                            }}
                                        />
                                    </>
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    ]}
                    data={products}
                    setData={setProducts}
                    onRowAdd={addProduct}
                    onRowDelete={deleteProduct}
                    onRowUpdate={updateProduct}
```

**setProductImage** is a state i was using before to store the image and upload it, but i had some problems and the table wasn't closing the add mode so i had to refresh manually and i didn't like that.

**onRowAdd** is an intern method that adds the new row to the table and **addProduct** is a method of mine that inserts the row data into the database, but neither onRowAdd and addProduct receives data from the image despite it actually uploads.

**onRowAdd** takes data from the entire row but for some reason doesn't take the image, i know this method works because i have another custom components which are working fine

```
File {name: "carbon.png", lastModified: 1623249483021, lastModifiedDate: Wed Jun 09 2021 09:38:03 GMT-0500 (hora de verano central), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 221097, …}
```

This is what it logs when i upload an image

Answer (score 0):

For me was hard to work with the rowAdd way. For things like this, I implement a manual way to save the data from the table. Doesn't have a good UX use the scroll to view what's the next row.

I prefer to use a custom form and open this form like a modal with a custom action.

Mi table approach look like this:

```
<MaterialTable
  title={<h1 className="font-medium">Users</h1>}
  localization={tableLocalization}
  columns={columns}
  data={data}
  options={{}}
  extraOptions={extraOptions}
  actions={[
    {
      icon: "add",
      tooltip: "Add new users",
      isFreeAction: true,
      onClick: (_event: any) => toggleForm(),
    },
  ]}
/>
```

The toggle form allows me to open a modal with all the fields and save them on the backend like normal form. Then, the new data is populated on the table.

Hopes this works for you.